# Positive input is returning as negative

Tags: c++, if-statement, debugging

My "num = -num" line inside of my "if (num<0)" line still affects results, even if my input is greater than 0.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter a positive number: ";
    int num{};
    std::cin >> num;

    if (num < 0)
        std::cout << "Negative number entered.  Making positive.\n";
        num = -num;

    std::cout << "You entered: " << num;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the first statement after `if (num < 0)` that you expect to execute if `num >= 0`?

Comment: A good compiler with good diagnostics enabled will [warn you of stuff like this](https://godbolt.org/z/Wvz8jvsPM). Good tools rock.

Answer (score 3):

To have multiple statements inside an `if`, you must use brackets.
And at this point of learning the language, I would recommend just **always** using brackets.

```
if (num < 0) {
  std::cout << "Negative number entered.  Making positive.\n";
  num = -num;
}
```

Unlike languages like python, leading whitespace is not meaningful to the compiler in C++.

Comment: In fact I think Python is the only language that considers indenting as significant, every other language requires some syntax to delimit a code block.